# How to permanently remove firewall check on program programmatically

Tags: c++, windows-xp, windows-firewall

I have an application that sends and receives data from another application running on the same machine using UDP protocol. Every time I open the program after I restart my computer, the firewall tells me it is blocked and asks if I want to allow access. Is there a way to permanently add this program to a "trusted" user list programmatically so that this dialogue stops popping up and so my users don't have to change anything on their machines manually?

The application is in VC++ 2005 and I'm running Windows XP SP3. I also needs something that will work on Windows 7, since we may be updating soon.

Comment: Tell the firewall to whitelist your program. How this is done depends on the firewall software installed. There's nothing you can do programatically to stop this. If you could, wouldn't viruses bypass the firewalls too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the socket to 127.0.0.1 or ::1 instead of 0.0.0.0 or :: and the firewall won't block you.

Comment: I'm binding my receive socket with a broadcast receive IP specified (0). So I suppose I should change this.